# DAX How to express today "one month ago"

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to create a card with last month's sales using Power BI Desktop.

For that, I need a measure that is capable of expressing today "one month ago"

For example, this month's sales is:

```
This month sales =
VAR ThisMonth =
    MONTH ( TODAY () )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        'orders'[SalesAmount];
        'calendar'[month_number] = ThisMonth;
        'calendar'[year] = 2017
    )
```

All time intelligence functions seem to be good to handle columns of date but not scalar values like this case is.

Also, because I'm using a card, there's no "filter context", therefore, I need a volatile function like `TODAY`.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not just add a column to the calendar table that is 1 for last month and 0 otherwise....then just use that in a calculate function as one of the filter context adjusters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you just do

```
LastMonth = MONTH(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1))
```

and use that instead of `ThisMonth` in your formula?

Answer (score 1):

TYLM Value = CALCULATE([Total Value],DATESMTD(DATEADD('CALENDAR'[DATE],-1,MONTH)))

if you have a calendar table the above should work for you.
You can limit the calendar table to Today as the latest date. the above measure will then work as you need.

Comment: [Total Value] is just a sum of a column that contains sales values.